# What lens mount does my Fujinon135 f/3.5 lens have?

Tags: lens-mount, old-lenses, vintage

What lens mount does this lens have? Also how cheap/easy would it be to buy/make an adapter to adapt this lens to Canon EF mount?

[image: view of lens from top/back]

[image: view of back of lens]

[image: front ring of lens]

in case you can't read it, it says EBC X-FUJINON-T and 1:3.5 f=135mm DM on the front ring of the lens.

[image: different angle to show rest of front ring text]

Comment: What does the ring on the front of the lens say?

Comment: @MichaelClark Oops, that pic didn't upload. It should be there now

Comment: Is there any reason this $40 Adapter wouldn't work: ["FotodioX Pro Lens Mount Adapter for Fujica X Lens to Canon EF-Mount Camera"](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/995132-REG/fotodiox_fujica_eos_g_canon_eos_ef_ef_s_lens.html)?

Comment: rob I'm not sure, ask @elkarrde who said it was not possible

Comment: @Rob It will work to achieve focus to infinity, but it's basically a small teleconverter: you increase focal length, decrease max. aperture, and take a hit on image quality (cheap glass).

Comment: Related: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: That's what you get for $40, pay more ... That adapter's "Multi-Coated Focus Correction Lens ... can be removed to render the adapter as an extension tube for macro shooting". So distortion free use is possible. --- This alternative is $23 and rated 4.7  from 77 reviews: https://www.kentfaith.com/KF06.061_canon-eos-to-fuji-x-mount-adapter -- so that brings back the question from the prior comment. You won't **make** a decent adapter for less than that in your basement, if you want cheap, that is cheaper.

Answer (score 7):

**X-Fujinon** says it all - that's Fujica X-mount, the one Fuji used on their SLR cameras from the early 1980s, before current mirrorless X-mount.

Fujica X-mount has focal flange depth of 43.5mm, so there is no way to effectively use this lens on Canon EF-mount body since EF-mount had bigger focal flange depth of 44mm - there is no way to achieve focus to infinity. On the other hand, you could remove the current mount, grind down a lens for 0.5mm, add an EF-mount onto it, possibly removing the aperture lever in the process, those levers are known for getting stuck on a mirror on Canon full-frame DSLRs. If you have an access to machinery needed for that, I'd say go for it, document the process and put it on the internet for future generations.

Also, you can use that lens on any mirrorless camera with just a simple, cheap adapter available almost everywhere.

Comment: Actually, there's no way to use it with a simple ring adapter, but [an adapter with a glass teleconverting element](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/995132-REG/fotodiox_fujica_eos_g_canon_eos_ef_ef_s_lens.html?ap=y&gclid=CjwKCAjwlcXXBRBhEiwApfHGTanSjOdDXHnpAx5wTOo-YJsBXEGk1e5Y0ouvSBQ4RkUG0-hYr0csZhoC4n8QAvD_BwE) can be used to achieve focus to infinity. You just take a hit on image quality.

Comment: Yeah, on DSLRs adapters with corrective optics are indeed needed. This one brings additional 1.4× crop factor, on APS-C 1.6× Canon bodies it sums up to 2.24×, so a 50mm lens would act like 112mm-equivalent, instead of 80mm-e. That's actually worse than using it on a microFourThirds mirrorless body with 2× crop factor.